# How do I transpose data that has multiple item responses in one column? IN SAS

Tags: sas, data-management

I have data that is reported in multiple sessions in one day, across multiple days. The data, however, is set up in this format:

```
Participant     Day     Session     Item_id    Item_info.            Response
     1           1         1           1         "In the past.."        2
     1           1         1           2         "In the present.."     5
     1           1         1           3         "In the future.."      10
     1           1         2           1         "In the past.."        4
     1           1         2           2         "In the present.."     5
     1           1         2           3         "In the future.."      3
     1           3         3           1         "In the past.."        6
     1           3         3           2         "In the present.."     6
     1           3         3           3         "In the future.."      8
     2           1         1           1         "In the past.."        7
     2           1         1           2         "In the present.."     7
     2           1         1           3         "In the future.."      7
```

etc.

My goal is to have the data look like this:

```
Participant     Day     Session     In the Past...    In the Present...      In the future...
     1           1         1           2                   5                       10
     1           1         2           4                   5                        3
     1           3         3           6                   6                        8
     2           1         1           7                   7                        7
```

I've tried using PROC TRANSPOSE

```
proc sort data=use out= x ;
by participant day session prompt_id;
run;

proc transpose data=x out=x2;
by participant day session prompt_id;
var response;
run;
```

But that didn't work. Instead, it looks like it created new columns based on the *session.*

I'm not sure if I am just not understanding proc transpose correctly, or if there are other things or techniquess I need to do.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Do the item info values contain actual double quotes ?

Comment: Hi Richard, No they do no actually include any quotations. That was just my way of showing they are characters instead of values.

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it solved but need to use the id and idlabel statements in proc transpose to get the result you are looking for.

Here is an example.

```
data use;
  participant=1; day=1; session=1; item_id=1; item_info="In the past.."   ; Response=2 ; output;
  participant=1; day=1; session=1; item_id=2; item_info="In the present.."; Response=5 ; output;
  participant=1; day=1; session=1; item_id=3; item_info="In the future.." ; Response=10; output;

  participant=1; day=1; session=2; item_id=1; item_info="In the past.."   ; Response=4 ; output;
  participant=1; day=1; session=2; item_id=2; item_info="In the present.."; Response=5 ; output;
  participant=1; day=1; session=2; item_id=3; item_info="In the future.." ; Response=3 ; output;

  participant=1; day=1; session=3; item_id=1; item_info="In the past.."   ; Response=6 ; output;
  participant=1; day=1; session=3; item_id=2; item_info="In the present.."; Response=6 ; output;
  participant=1; day=1; session=3; item_id=3; item_info="In the future.." ; Response=8 ; output;

  participant=2; day=1; session=1; item_id=1; item_info="In the past.."   ; Response=7 ; output;
  participant=2; day=1; session=1; item_id=2; item_info="In the present.."; Response=7 ; output;
  participant=2; day=1; session=2; item_id=3; item_info="In the future.." ; Response=7 ; output;
run;
options validvarname=v7; *<- to avoid numbers as varnames;
proc sort data=use;
    by participant day session;
run;
proc transpose data=use out=t_use(drop=_name_);
    id item_id; /* if you prefer the text as var name use item_info instead */
    idlabel item_info;
    by participant day session;
    var response;
run;    
proc print data=t_use label;
run;
```

The output data will look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=WORK.HAVE
    OUT=WORK.WANT
    NAME=Source
    LABEL=Label
;
    BY Participant Day Session;
    ID "Item_Info."n;
    VAR Response;

RUN;
```

your output should look like this[image: transposed]

Comment: Hi Niqua, This is what my output looks similar to what you described / show. My issue however, is that the responses 2, 5, and 10 are in the same session so I need them to be in the same row.

Comment: That can be done by creating new column, `sum(t1.'In the past', t1.'In the present',t1.'In the future')`

Since 2 of them will always be missing, you should get values stacked to a single column